# Issue unused parameter warnings in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, parameters, warnings

I am using XCode Version 6.0.1 (6A317) with Mac OS X Mavericks. In my C++ project, I recently discovered a bug that could have been detected by the fact that I forgot to use one of the parameters of a function. How can I get XCode to issue a warning in such cases?

For instance, the following function ought to result in two warnings (for two unused parameters):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your project’s build settings. In the search field at the top, enter “unused”.

You will see several matching settings under Warnings. One of them is Unused Parameters. Turn it on.

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly once I managed to find "build settings." Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you define a function, you don't need to write a concrete parameter name for unused parameters, i.e.

```
#include<iostream>

int foo(int a, int, int c)
{
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    foo(1,2,3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, but this does not answer the question.